# Send Email via OleVariant Outlook with embedded image

Tags: image, delphi, outlook

I am trying to send Email from my program via Outlook with embedded image. But a picture is not showing in the email.
I set CID in HTML and property by attachment.
Here is my simple code:
For test you can create form and put button on it, replace E-Mailadress and picture path.

```
unit unit1;

interface

uses
 Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, OutlookXP, comobj,  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
 Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, system.Diagnostics;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
   Button1: TButton;
   procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 private
   { Private-Deklarationen }
 public
   { Public-Deklarationen }
 end;

 TOutlookEmail = class
 private
   FOutlookApp: OleVariant;
 public
   constructor Create;
   destructor Destroy; override;
   procedure SendEmailWithEmbeddedImage(const aRecipient, aSubject, aBody, aImagePath: string);
 end;

var
 Form1: TForm1;



implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 b : String;
 mailOut : TOutlookEmail;
begin
 mailout := TOutlookEmail.Create;
 
 b := '<html><bodystyle=' +
 'font-family:"Tahoma";font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:8pt' +
 '><fontcolor="#000000">Hello world<IMG src="cid:1" width="606" height="606" ></font></body></html>';

 mailout.SendEmailWithEmbeddedImage('xxx@googlemail.com', 'Test', b, 'C:\Delphi\1.png');
end;

constructor TOutlookEmail.Create;
begin
 inherited;
 FOutlookApp := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
end;

destructor TOutlookEmail.Destroy;
begin
 FOutlookApp := Unassigned;
 inherited;
end;

procedure TOutlookEmail.SendEmailWithEmbeddedImage(const aRecipient, aSubject, aBody,
 aImagePath: string);
var
 MailItem,
 Attachment: OleVariant;
begin
   MailItem := FOutlookApp.CreateItem(0);

   MailItem.Subject := ASubject;
   MailItem.To := aRecipient;
   mailitem.BodyFormat := olFormatHTML;
   MailItem.htmlBody := aBody;

   if FileExists(aImagePath) then
   begin
     Attachment := MailItem.Attachments.Add(aImagePath);
     Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty('http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F', '<1>');
   end;
   MailItem.Send;
   MailItem := Unassigned;
end;

end.
```

If i do display instead of send. Outlook shows me image in the mail, after i press send button it reach recipient with only empty shape and picture as attachment.

I need some help how can I do it right.
With best regards.

Comment: you could base64 encode the image into the html

Comment: Use another name for the CID, p.e. **ImageId1** not just a number

Comment: @complete_stranger , I am not sure that is right way to encode pictures into base64. It will be very large HTML-Text. But its work. I tried it out.

Comment: @Garada , I did it with "image001" too. Above is just an example. btw it doesnt work.

Comment: Which Outlook version? I tested the code with OL 2021 and a Gmail account as recipient.

Comment: @Garada ,  I mean we use Outlook 2021 too. Is picture shows in the email or its just an attachment with empty picture ?

Comment: The image shows inline in the email. Did you try *image001* without *<>* symbols  in HTML and the MAPI property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255414/discussion-between-garada-and-sausagerus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a name with only a number fails as a CID name, this is a working code using an alphanumeric CID name

```
var
  OL,
  MailItem,
  Attachment: OleVariant;
begin
  OL := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  MailItem := OL.CreateItem(0);

  MailItem.Subject := 'Subject';
  MailItem.To := 'xxx@gmail.com';
  mailitem.BodyFormat := olFormatHTML;
  MailItem.htmlBody := '<html>' +
                       '<body style=font-family:"Tahoma";font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:8pt>' +
                       '<fontcolor="#000000">Hello world<IMG src="cid:ImageId1" width="606" height="606"></font></body></html>';

  Attachment := MailItem.Attachments.Add('C:\PathTo\1.png');
  Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty('http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F', 'ImageId1');

  MailItem.Recipients.ResolveAll;
  MailItem.Send;
  MailItem := Unassigned;
  OL := Unassigned;
end;
```

Comment: it works with numbers too, my problem was <> symbols in attachment property